# Access and VBA Coding

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to have my combo box in my form to allow me to add data if it is not in on the list.  My combo box is named cmbTitle  and the table name that I am pulling the combo box info from is tblDVDs.  My combo box is not listing the titles though it is listing the ID numbers which I do not want and the code I have does not allow me to add it to the combo box nor update my table I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  I am sorry I am an amatuer at VBA could someone help me please.  Below is my code for my form with the combo box:

```
Private Sub cmbTitle_Change()
On Error GoTo myError
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone
rst.FindFirst "ID = " & Me!cmbTitle
Me.Bookmark = rst.Bookmark
Me!cmbTitle = Null

leave:
 If Not rst Is Nothing Then Set rst = Nothing
 Exit Sub

 myError:
MsgBox "Record Not Found"
Resume leave
End Sub

Private Sub cmbTitle_NotInList(NewData As String, Response As Integer)

Dim db As Database

Dim LSQL As String
Dim LResponse As Integer
Dim ctl As Control

On Error GoTo Err_Execute

'Category combo box control
Set ctl = Me!Task

LResponse = MsgBox(NewData & " is a new item.  Do you wish to add it to the combo          box?", vbYesNo, "Add Item")

'User responded "Yes" to adding the new item to the combo box
If LResponse = vbYes Then
    Set db = CurrentDb()

    'Insert new item into underlying table
    LSQL = "insert into tblDVDs (tblDVDs) values ('" & NewData & "')"

    db.Execute LSQL, dbFailOnError

    Set db = Nothing

    'Set Response argument to indicate that data is being added.
    Response = acDataErrAdded

Else
    'Set Response argument to suppress error message and undo changes
    Response = acDataErrContinue
    ctl.Undo
End If

On Error GoTo 0

Exit Sub
```

`   Err_Execute:
    ctl.Undo
    MsgBox "Action failed"

```
End Sub

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the combo box to have 2 columns

column 1 ID

Colum 2 Title

and set the column width to: 0",1"  to hide the ID on the combo box

Your Insert statement needs to be

Insert into tblDVDS (titlefield) values

I am assuming the ID is an autonumber
the rest of the code looks correct.

Comment: Thank you so much yes the ID is an autonumber, what is the code like for column width I have not done that yet